# Older settings did not load after newest 3.6 update!

Tags: customization

I recently updated to 3.6 and the usual "load older settings" prompt came up. I clicked on it but it didn't seem to do anything? My addons are all gone and I tried reverting to an older version of Blender, but it refuses to open if I do so. Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: What Blender version did you update from? What operating system? What do you mean "My addons are all gone..."?

Comment: I was using 3.5 before updating to 3.6. I am using Windows 10. My addons as in my user preference. Everything seems to be reset to default.